# scrollRangeToVisible doesn't update contentOffset until a refresh

Tags: xcode, scroll, uitextview

I am calling scrollRangeToVisible on a UITextView to scroll to the top. I then ask for its contentOffset, and this comes back as (0,0).
However, after a screen refresh, the contentOffset comes back as (0,8)  - probably something to do with the font of the text. And the (0,8) is the correct value as it works for the rest of my app if I hard-code it in.
My problem is that I need to get the (0,8) as soon as I have made the call to scrollRangeToVisible. Perhaps it is not there because it needs that screen refresh - if so, how can I force a refresh and return immediately to do my further processing.
Alternatively, it may be animating the scrollRangeToVisible, and therefore the animation is right at the start when I get contentOffset. So how do I stop the animation?

```
NSRange start = NSMakeRange(0,1);
[self.recipe_view scrollRangeToVisible:start];
start_scroll = self.recipe_view.contentOffset;
```